# <form> is wrapped by custom Card component in react. How to style with them in external css file

Tags: css, reactjs

```
<Card className="input">
        <form onSubmit={addUserHandler} className="input">
            <label htmlFor="username">Username</label>
            <input id="username" type="text" />
            <label htmlFor="age">Age (Years)</label>
            <input id="age" type="text" />
            <button type="submit">Add User</button>
        </form>
</Card>
```

Now the Card component below.

```
return <div className="card">{props.children}</div>;
```

How to align this two for css styling?

Comment: didn't you try giving inner components class ?

Answer (score 0):

css

```
.card > .input-form {
    background-color: gray
}
```

code as below

```
<Card className="input">
        <form onSubmit={addUserHandler} className="input-form">
            <label htmlFor="username">Username</label>
            <input id="username" type="text" />
            <label htmlFor="age">Age (Years)</label>
            <input id="age" type="text" />
            <button type="submit">Add User</button>
        </form>
</Card>
```

Now the Card component below.

```
return <div className="card">{props.children}</div>;
```